# Google app maker testing approach

Tags: google-app-maker

After development how can we test the application, is there any tools available for unit testing or any automation testing can be done in app maker.

If the above things cannot be done means the only option is manual testing. Please suggest me any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DL** At this time App Maker doesn't provide any out of the box tools for unit testing.

However if you really need to test you application, you can look in direction of *browser automation* frameworks that allow you to record, replay and assert end user actions, take screenshots and run pixel by pixel comparison...

You can also go fancy and try to use some nice js testing framework, but in this case you'll expose your tests to end users via App Maker runtime.